# Symfony returns "MongoId Class not found" error

Tags: mongodb, docker, ubuntu-14.04, symfony

I am using Symfony3 and I have used mongo db in my application.

I have include the following in my composer.json file

```
"doctrine/mongodb-odm": "^1.0@dev",
"doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "^3.0@dev",
```

I have tried couple of solutions from internet but following error is coming

```
Fatal error: Class 'MongoId' not found in /var/www/vendor/doctrine/mongodb-odm/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Id/AutoGenerator.php on line 34
```

Comment: Have you installed the `mongo` PHP extension? If you are on PHP7 you have to install `alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter` as well.

Comment: Yes it was mongo PHP extension problem. I was using php5.6.27 cli and docker. I have fixed it thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try \MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID instead.

customers->findOne(array(
                  '_id' => new\MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID('doc id')));